# Unexpected github action trigger

Tags: github, triggers, workflow

This github action runs on a pull request to develop.  This isn't what I expected and I could use some fishing tips on how to understand/debug why it is triggered.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
```

`develop` is the default branch for the repository.  I mention this because this action isn't triggered when I push to a feature branch.   It is triggered on a pull request to master.

Comment: I seem to have resolved this by removing the pull_request stanza.   It seems that everything runs on the push.